# Most Efficient Integer Array to Histogram Algortihm JAVA (CountingSort?)

Tags: java, arrays, histogram, processing-efficiency, counting-sort

I'm trying to implement an algorithm in java which takes in an array of integers from 1 to 100 and prints them as a histogram. I believe I've deduced a linear solution for this but don't know if it is O(n) or O(10n) etc. I have based the algorithm on a counting sort as I understand it to be the most efficient array sorting algorithm. Are there more efficient ways to sort arrays in the context of displaying them as histograms than a manipulated counting sort?

The method so far:

```
public static void histogram(int[] array){
    for(int i = 0; i< array.length; i++){
        array[i] = (array[i] - 1)/10;
    }

    //create quantity array of size 10 and fill with 0
    int[] quantity = new int[10];
    for(int i = 0; i <= 9; i++){
        quantity[i] = 0;    
    }

    //increment value of quantity index = array[i]
    for(int i = 0; i< array.length; i++){
        quantity[array[i]]++;
    }

    //set values of number group column in histogram
    int low = 1;
    int high = 10;

    //string to pad the rows with shorter group names (1-10)
    String pad = "  ";

    //start building histogram
    StringBuilder his = new StringBuilder(
            "______________________________________________ \n"); //ceiling 

    //loop 10 times (number of groups = 10)
    for(int i = 0; i<= 9; i++){
        his.append(low + " - " + high + pad + " | "); //number group column
        //append asterisks equal to value stored in quantity[i]
        for(int j = 0; j < quantity[i]; j++){
            his.append("*"); 
        }

        his.append("\n");   //move to next line

        //set values of next number group
        low += 10;
        high += 10;

        //pad for 11-20 ... 81-90
        pad = " ";
        if (high == 100){
            pad = "";   //pad for 91-100
        }            
    }

    his.append("______________________________________________"); //floor
    System.out.print(his); //print entire historgram
}
```

Here is an example of the output:

---

1 - 10   | **********

11 - 20  | **********

21 - 30  | *********

31 - 40  | *******

41 - 50  | ***********

51 - 60  | ***********

61 - 70  | **********

71 - 80  | **********

81 - 90  | ************

91 - 100 | **********

---

FOR ARRAY OF SIZE 100 TOTAL TIME TO PERFORM ALGORITHM: 473397ns

(stackoverflow seems to mess up the formatting a bit but everything prints in line)

Comment: You don't need to know if it is `O(n)` or `O(10n)` since `O(n) = O(10n)`. Also you do not need to fill an `int` array with `0`; Java does this for you.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a request for a code review, consider posting on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Hi, I can remove the part of the question asking to review the code as my main question is more related to the efficiency of using a countingSort to make a histogram as opposed to an alternative method.

Comment: think about it logically, unless you're caching information (like already calculated totals when you're adding new elements to the count), you'll always need O(n) information (the info of every element). Aggregating this beforehand while you add is one way to achieve a "usual" O(1).